# Using an iterative formula to calculate all possible values of a function (python)

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

This is what i've tried so far to calculate all possible values of w. I am aware i will need some kind of loop but i am still quite new to python so i am unsure of what to use

```
m = arange(200, 1200, 0.1)
k = arange(1, 7, 0.1)    
w = math.sqrt(k / m)
```

i would like this to give me a list of all possible values of w from the given possible values of m and k

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: @smac89 when i run it it gives the error operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (60,) (10000,). I guess because they are not the same size it cant complete the operation

Comment: You should include that detail in your question. Anyways it makes sense. You have an array of 10000 elements and another of 60 elements, so how do you want to do `k/m`? Include this detail also in your question

Comment: @smac89 i would like the end result (w) to be a list of all possible variations of k/m given the parameters m = arange(200, 1200, 0.1)
k = arange(1, 7, 0.1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the below (*not using numpy - just pure python*)

```
import math

m_lst = (200, 1200, 0.1)
k_lst = (1, 7, 0.1)    
w_lst = []

for m in m_lst:
  for k in k_lst:
    w_lst.append(math.sqrt(k / m))
print(w_lst)
```

output

```
[0.07071067811865475, 0.18708286933869708, 0.022360679774997897, 0.02886751345948129, 0.07637626158259733, 0.00912870929175277, 3.1622776601683795, 8.366600265340756, 1.0]
```

Comment: `(200, 1200, 0.1)` is just a tuple of 3 elements. Although your solution will still work, I just wanted to draw your attention to that

Comment: @smac89 I am aware to the fact that `m_lst` and `k_lst` are tuples.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this purely using numpy, then this is something you can do:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange

m = arange(200, 1200, 0.1)
k = arange(1, 7, 0.1)
w = np.sqrt(k[: np.newaxis] / m)
```

The `k[: np.newaxis]` is necessary so that numpy is able to generate a result of the right dimensions, otherwise, a solution similar to what the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813026/2089675) does, will be necessary.